# MongoDB : How can i include an Filed which is not in collection in mongoexport

Tags: mongodb

This is my MongoExport Query which will generate a CSV Report of Collection people

mongoexport --csv -o /tmp/people.csv -d school -c people -f firstName,lastName,telephone

This is working Fine .

```
firstName   lastName    telephone   

Eval        Manual      9087876787
```

Now i want an Extra Field Called Date (Which should be Yesterday Date )

So this should look like  (With an Extra Filed Date Added to it )

```
firstName   lastName    telephone     Date

Eval        Manual      9087876787   30-04-2013
```

Please let me know how to do this , as this is in need for me .

Comment: I suppose that extra field doesn't exist in the collection?

Comment: yes , that extra field is not present in Collection , but it should be hardcoded to always yesterday Date .

Comment: Might be best to add a field to the collection then using update, because afaik mongoexport cannot add calculated or constant fields to it output the way select can.

Comment: Just script it and add it to the CSV as a second step.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do that ??